# Automatic variable initialization and copy/move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I have a snippet:

```
struct MyCass2 {
  MyCass2() {}

  MyCass2(MyCass2 const&) = delete;

  MyCass2(MyCass2&&) = delete;
};

int
main() {
  auto a = MyCass2();
}
```

This results in

```
main.cpp:43:8: error: call to deleted constructor of 'MyCass2'
  auto a = MyCass2();
       ^   ~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:38:3: note: 'MyCass2' has been explicitly marked deleted here
  MyCass2(MyCass2&&) = delete;
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Why I thought there will be a template type deduction and a direct initialization after all? Can somebody explain how the automatic variable initialization work in this case?

Comment: @Nawaz: In the `auto` :-)

Comment: Is `auto&& = MyClass();` good enough for you? ([Demo](https://ideone.com/YrXjoW))

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I was sure that this `auto var=initializer` is kind of a syntax overloading. Like with copy initialization `T var=initializer`, where instead of `operator=`  a copy constructor is called. So can you answer my question ?

Comment: Note that any decent compiler will optimize away the call to the copy/move constructor but it still has to be there for it to compile.

Comment: See Q&A 6 here: https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why I thought there will be a template type deduction

`auto` uses the rules of template argument deduction to deduce the type of the variable. In this case, the type will be deduced to be `MyCass2`.

> and a direct initialization after all?

`a` is not [direct-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), because you used [copy-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) - see the syntax labeled (1).

> how the automatic variable initialization work in this case?

`a` is copy-initialized from the temporary on the right hand side of `=`. However, since the type is neither copyable, nor movable, the copy initialization is not allowed.

> But I [defined] the move/copy constructors and neither of them was called, how is that?

The default constructor was used to initialize the temporary. The call to the move constructor in the copy initialization is allowed to be [elided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

> I was sure that this auto var=initializer is kind of a syntax overloading. Like with copy initialization T var=initializer, where instead of operator= a copy constructor is called.

Well, it isn't. Here, `auto` is used for, and only for deducing the type. Once the type has been deduced, the expression is entirely equivalent to

```
MyCass2 a = MyCass2();
```

Comment: But I declared the move/copy constructors and neither of them was called, how is that? The usual constructor was called.

Comment: Sorry for a confusion, I mean I define them (they are not deleted anymore).

Comment: But in this case there was no consideration of copy elision, correct? The temporary was constructed and then the move constructor was selected as the best match?

Comment: @flatmouse see the linked page about copy elision: "Optimizes out copy- and *move*-constructors". So yes, the move is elided. Although, it is indeed move constructor that would be selected, I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @user2079303 Aha, I should have read the linked page... Great answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
auto a = MyCass2();
```

Uses copy/move initialization.  Now since you have a have a move constructor declared (yes a deleted function is still a declared function) the compiler going to try and use that to move the temporary into `a` as it is the best match.  When it goes to do that though it tries to use the deleted move constructor.  Trying to use a deleted function is ill formed and the compiler generates an error.

If you want to allow the above code you work you need to have either the copy or move constructor defined.  Do note that in a case like

```
auto a = some_named_myclass2_object;
```

The copy constructor needs to be defined as `some_named_myclass2_object` is an lvalue and cannot be moved from without `std::move`